# Is everything really that bad?

Tags: discussion

Please could you tell me why my question is getting downvotes and closevotes for being OPINION BASED? Could you just tell me other so popular and (as it seems) progressive-thinking developers' community where I can ask such questions?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26339852/forking-bootstraps-grid-system

Comment: How is _"would creating this fork will be useful for developers?"_ _not_ opinion based?

Comment: Your question basically is: *would creating this fork will be useful for developers?* You are soliciting for opinions there. (Disclaimer: I didn't vote).

Comment: Also, [throwing a tantrum because your question is closed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26339852/forking-bootstraps-grid-system#comment41342184_26339852) won't work in your favor.

Comment: Ok. So where else should I ask a question like that?

Comment: You already got feedback in the comments, you'll not get a different verdict on Meta, I'm afraid. There is no Stack Exchange site for your question.

Comment: If you want a discussion forum, the door is to your left.

Answer (score 5):

Quoting from your question:

> So the question is, maybe there's ALREADY the fork of Bootstrap that realizes that principle. And if no, *would creating this fork will be useful for developers?*

[Italics mine.]

Usefulness is relative to the specific goals of the people who might be potential users of your fork. There's no definite answer to your question.

I do not know of a place on the SE network for a question like this. Even those sites that accept more conceptual questions would probably reject such an open-ended one.

Comment: ["We already tried supporting those questions, we even gave them their own site. Sadly, it didn't work out..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773)